# Change a cell's background color dynamically according to a RGB value stored in other cells

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

I'm trying to write a function in Excel that will set the background color of the active cell according to the values stored in other three cells (each of those three cells store a numeric value from 0 to 255, depending on the color R, G or B).

So the A1 cell is 150, the B1 cell is 220 and the C1 cell is 90 (that's RGB(150, 220, 90)). I need that the D1 cell's color is that RGB declared before (some kind of green), and also, if I place the function in D2, it will select the RGB stored in A2, B2 and C2, and so on...

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Please explain further. I don't get it.

Comment: You should be able to use code like this to set the colour of a cell `SomeCell.Interior.Color = RGB(150, 220, 90)`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

UDF version:

```
Function myRGB(r, g, b)

    Dim clr As Long, src As Range, sht As String, f, v

    If IsEmpty(r) Or IsEmpty(g) Or IsEmpty(b) Then
        clr = vbWhite
    Else
        clr = RGB(r, g, b)
    End If

    Set src = Application.ThisCell
    sht = src.Parent.Name

    f = "Changeit(""" & sht & """,""" & _
                  src.Address(False, False) & """," & clr & ")"
    src.Parent.Evaluate f
    myRGB = ""
End Function

Sub ChangeIt(sht, c, clr As Long)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range(c).Interior.Color = clr
End Sub
```

Usage (entered in D1):

```
=myRGB(A1,B1,C1)
```

Comment: Never thought of calling a sub from the function to do the change, NICE.

Comment: Beautiful. This technique can be used to achieve many other things as well.

Comment: This is just what I needed!! Thank you Tim!

Comment: TIM, User Defined Function, given by you is  an useful tool, generated a 3000 pixel RGB values into an image. Thanks.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm going a bit crazy trying to adapt this to take a text value. i.e. `=G4 & "hi" & myRGB(255,0,0,"Hello I am Red") & myRGB(0,0,255,"Hello I am Blue") & " " & H4`

Comment: What is the end result you want though?

Answer (score 7):

In **D1** enter:

```
=A1 & "," & B1 & "," & C1
```

and in the worksheet code area, enter the following event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Range("D1").Interior.Color = RGB(Range("A1"), Range("B1"), Range("C1"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That does not seem very useful... with hardcoded ranges

Comment: @ExcelHero  The code was "designed" with the question in mind.

Comment: Even if those three cells are actually all the OP wants, your solution is not a good design. Why run this every single time the worksheet calculates? The task prescribed should be kept to an absolute minimum number of times executed.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent My apologies. Reading it back now I see it was quite a bit harsher than I intended.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, your code works perfectly for cell D1! Is there a way to make this code work in any given cell, drawing the RGB data from any given group of three cells? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand on Tim Williams terrific answer. I needed to be able to show a hex value in my cells based on other cells. I also want the font set to either white or black because of this. So I modified the function as follows:

```
Function hexColor(r, g, b)

    Dim bclr As Long, fclr As Long, src As Range, sht As String, f, v

     If IsEmpty(r) Or IsEmpty(g) Or IsEmpty(b) Then
        bclr = vbWhite
        fclr = vbBlack
    Else
        bclr = RGB(r, g, b)
        If ((r * 0.299) + (g * 0.587) + (b * 0.114) > 186) Then
            fclr = vbBlack
        Else
            fclr = vbWhite
        End If
    End If

    Set src = Application.ThisCell
    sht = src.Parent.Name

    f = "Changeit(""" & sht & """,""" & _
                  src.Address(False, False) & """," & bclr & "," & fclr & ")"
    src.Parent.Evaluate f

    Dim hr As String, hg As String, hb As String

    hr = Right("0" & Hex(r), 2)
    hg = Right("0" & Hex(g), 2)
    hb = Right("0" & Hex(b), 2)

    hexColor = "#" & hr & hg & hb
End Function

Sub ChangeIt(sht, c, bclr As Long, fclr As Long)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range(c).Interior.Color = bclr
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range(c).Font.Color = fclr
End Sub
```

This means I can enter the following two cell values: `=hexColor(185,201,225)` and
`=hexColor(115,146,198)` and get the following result:

[image: Excel sheet]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would want this to work with the entire columns instead of just row 1, here is the VBA procedure for the worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then
            If .Column < 4 Then
                Cells(.Row, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(Cells(.Row, 1), Cells(.Row, 2), Cells(.Row, 3))
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: I do not know what you mean by the following and so have not addressed it: `and also, if I place the function in D2, it will select the RGB stored in A2, B2 and C2`.

Comment: EH, I guess the answer of Tim addressed the pending issue. A UDF that the user can place anywhere.

Comment: @A.S.H Maybe. Still don't know for sure what OP meant.

Comment: Small typo code to set color - last value (blue) has a period before "Cells(.Row, 3)"

Should be:                 
Cells(.Row, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(Cells(.Row, 1), Cells(.Row, 2), Cells(.Row, 3))